# How do you post content to a specific template position?

Tags: templates, joomla

I purchased a template / theme from RocketTheme, but I can't figure out how to add content at a specific position.

The templates have "module positions" that collapse. I'd like to add some content at one of the module positions.

If I add articles, they seem to go into "mainbody". But I'd like to have content in other areas of the template.

How do I take some text, images, or other content, and get them to display in these other positions (i.e., TOP-A, or FEATURE-A, etc)?

I've tried this

Go to Extensions->Module Manager

Select "New", Select "Sections"

Under "Details", I select Position->Top-A

I give it a title.

Nothing seems to happen. I don't see anything new exposed in the admin UI, and I don't see a way to get any content into this newly defined section. What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to JED and look up html in module or content in module or content in component there are a bunch of them.   http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=module+content&start=20

Essentially

you create and save an article.  Make sure it is saved to a section or category on your menu
open the module one of the paramaters will ask for the article id...decide which position and which pages you want it on and then publish.

You can also get modules that will take some or all of your articles in a category and then show them either as a slidedhow or one randomly when someone visits the page